# jquery ensuring that mouseup is fired

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseup

I have an app that uses mouseup and down to draw elements. The problem is that if for any reason the mouseup event is not fired after mousedown ( let's say I introduce an escape key that cancels drawing the new element), the element would be "incomplete", and hence it would cause problem. So I want to know if there is any mechanism that I can use inside mousedown to ensure that mouseup is fired after it, and if not, destroy the new element ?

Comment: Attach the clear event on `keyup` as well if `e.which === ESC`

Comment: Actually, that comment is the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're gonna have to destroy the drawing on the events which you can think of that would make the mouseup not fire following the mousedown -- pressing keys, releasing the mouse outside of the drawing region, right clicking while left click is still holding down, switching the window with alt+tab while drawing, computer being struck with lightening in the middle of a tornado while drawing, etc.